# Key up event that executes when 5 characters are entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a function that fires when a user enters in 5 characters in an input field.

However, whenever I place additional characters after the 5 has been fulfilled it keeps on firing the event.

How do I prevent this from occurring?

```
$(function(){
    var $zipEntry = $('#zipEntry').bind('keyup',function(event) { //bind to key up, doesn't require 
    //make sure that there are 5 numbers... or length = 5 since numeric only input
    var $this = $(this); // cache $(this)
    
        if ($this.val().length == 5){ // use cached 
            console.log("There are 5 characters!!");
            $this.trigger('zipEntered'); 
        }
    });
```

Comment: each time you the anon function gets called on a keyup, you are resetting var $this = $(this)

Comment: I don't see any issue with this. can you put together a demo at jsbin.com?

Comment: you want to fire the event only when it is equal to 5 not less than 5 or greathan 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try unbinding the event after you're done listening for it.

```
if ($this.val().length == 5){
    console.log("There are 5 characters!!");
    $this.trigger('zipEntered');
    $('#zipEntry').unbind('keyup');
}
```

Comment: What happen when user wants to correct the 5th character if keyup() is unbind?

Comment: @Danosaure I only answered the question as it was written. There are definitely potential flaws in implementing this, but speculating on all the potentialities is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: @stevelove Sorry, i was asking the OP. I'm still amazed why it doesn't work, but maybe because I don't understand JQuery.

Comment: @Danosaure No apology necessary. I'm also not certain why the OP's code doesn't work as written, but I can only assume there's more to this incomplete snippet that's causing an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you need use "greater or equal" instead "equal"

```
if ($this.val().length >= 5){
```

*Also, why do you use $ in variable names??*

Comment: If you come from a $variable name language like PHP you may find code hard to read without them.  I have to resist the urge sometimes.

Comment: Using a dollar sign in variable names is common practice when working with jQuery to indicate that the variable holds a reference to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

Can't the problem be corrected at the source? Put a maxlength on the input field?

Comment: No. The event gets fired on completion of the 5 characters. Max length is already in the input markup and does not apply here.  You can still enter in characters but it won't be displayed.

Comment: @ectype: I see. If the user press "shift" it would fire the event. From the user's experience point of view, it's acceptable in your scenario to not allow him to correct his answer? For this type of problem, I usually get an intermediate variable and compare it to the actual value before fire the "trigger".

Comment: In this scenario the entire picture or code in this instance would give you a proper context which I probably should've said from the get go. What is implemented is jQuery's numeric which only allows numeric keys and delete / backspace. So since the prompt only allows the user to enter a five digit zip code this is why the other characters are disabled. The zip code validation is done on the back end and if it does not match up with the geo service it gives the user feedback stating to re-enter their zip code.